# How can I remove non-breaking spaces from a JSoup 'Document'?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-entities

How can I remove these:

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

or

```
<td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
```

from my JSoup 'Document'? I've tried many methods, but these non-breaking space characters do not match anything with normal JSoup expressions or Selectors.

Comment: Is it not possible to open the document in an IDE or text editor like Notepad++ and the do a find and replace? Or do you mean you need to do it programmatically?

Comment: JSoup is a library that parses FETCHED HTML data for an application. So no, what you're suggesting is not only not possible, but not applicable. :)

Comment: Does this apply to the entire document or only within `<td>` elements? By the way, are you aware that MSIE browser has rendering problems with completely empty `<td>` elements? A `<td>&nbsp;</td>` is namely a classic workaround for this MSIE misbehaviour.

Comment: Have you tried something like  `response.replaceAll("&nbsp", "")` before it goes through Jsoup?

Comment: @tw16 I want to remove the entire line, not just the &nbsp;. Plus, I am using JSoup.connect("http://www.blah.com").get() which doesn't allow you to modify the document before parsing.

Comment: "The entire line" is too ambiguous. HTML does not have notion of "lines". You should then really feed `URL#openStream()` through a `BufferedReader` and then ignore the `readLine()` whenever it `contains("&nbsp;")`.

Comment: @BalusC I'm certain there has to be a way to delete every element that has &nbsp; in it, so I would rather not have to go to all of that work as a workaround. The JSoup website suggests getting help on Stackoverflow with #jsoup tag, but so far this is a very simple issue which remains unresolved. :(

Comment: It is possible. But you said to remove the entire line. This is not possible with Jsoup. You can only select and remove elements, not lines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The HTML entity `&nbsp;` ([Unicode character NO-BREAK SPACE U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)) can in Java be represented by the character `\u00a0`. Assuming that you want to remove every *element* which contains that character as own text (and thus not every *line* as you said in a comment), then the following ought to work:

```
document.select(":containsOwn(\u00a0)").remove();
```

If you really mean to remove the entire *line* then your best bet is really to scan HTML yourself line by line.

Comment: document.select(":containsOwn(\u00a0)").remove();
it is removing all elements having space 
but I want to remove only any tag having &nbsp;
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html#:~:text=p%3AcontainsOwn(jsoup)%20finds,The%20search%20is%20case%20insensitive.
then I tried this 
:containsWholeOwnText("&nbsp;")
but its throwing error 
unexpected toke at containsWholeOwnText(\u00a0)
I am not sure what's the issue

Comment: *"it is removing all elements having space"*. False. It is removing all elements having non-breaking space, exactly the `\u00a0` character represented by the HTML entity `&nbsp;`. This is already explained in the answer. If it is not working for you, then I guess your actual problem is different. Are you perhaps trying to say that you're seeing **literally** `&nbsp;` among the text presented by the web browser itself? So in other words, the HTML source code contains *actually* `&amp;nbsp;` instead of `&nbsp;`?