# how to read htm file inside a zip file?

Tags: java, html, file, zip

I have a zip file which contains Index.htm. I should read content of Index.htm and find a date(**December 2011**) inside it and create a directory with this date and then extract zip file inside this directory.

**this is html file:**

```
<HTML>    
  <HEAD></HEAD>    
  <BODY>    
  <A Name="TopOfPage"></A>    
  <TABLE Width="100%" Border="0" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">    
   <TR> 
     <TD Width="30%"><A HRef="HeaderTxt/HetBCFI.htm">Het B.C.F.I.</A></TD>    
   </TR>      
  </TABLE>    
  <TABLE Width="100%" Border="0" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
   <TR> 
    <TD RowSpan="2" Width="10"></TD>
    <TD Width="70%"><STRONG><FONT Face="Arial" Size="2">Gecommentarieerd   Geneesmiddelenrepertorium</FONT></STRONG></TD> 
    <TD Width="29%" Align="Right" Class= "Datum">&nbsp;
   December 2011&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </TD>
  <TD Rowspan="2" Width="10"></TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE> </BODY> </HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is proper end Code that i used: thanks to all you by providing usefull tips**

```
public static String getDateWithinHtmlInsideZipFile(File archive) {
      ZipFile zp = new ZipFile(archive);
      InputStream in = zp.getInputStream (zp.getEntry ("Index.htm"));

      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8", "");

    return doc.body().getElementsByClass("Datum").text().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

1. Use java.util.zip package [to read the html](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingtheContentsofaZIPFile.htm)
2. Use Some html parser (I would recommend [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)) to get the date string. [Here is link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396098/how-to-parse-a-table-from-html-using-jsoup) that would help in your case.

Once you have the date string, create the dir you wanted.

**EDIT**: To remove `&nbsp;`,you could one of the followings,

- Create another document element with the string containing `&nbsp;` and do the following

  `document.select(":containsOwn(\u00a0)").remove();` (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034775/how-can-i-remove-non-breaking-spaces-from-a-jsoup-document))
- Use Following (Assuming your string to be cleaned is `htmlString`)

  `Jsoup.parse(htmlString).text();`
- Use String's `replaceAll()` function to get rid of `&nbsp;`.

Comment: When i pars htm file i get &nbsp; befor and end of my string.
How can i get rid of it?

Comment: Updated my answer to address your concerns.

Comment: `String date = doc.body().getElementsByClass("Datum").html().toString().replaceAll("&nbsp;","").trim();`

Answer (score 2):

Several steps:

1. Use the java.util.zip package and create a decompressed stream.
2. Use an XML parser (like JSoup) to walk the nodes, and...
3. Use a regex, or a regex with a date parser (such as SimpleDateFormat) to pick out the date.

This makes the assumptions that the date you're looking for is always in a text node.

Comment: Extra step 1.5: ZipFile zp = new ZipFile ("xxx.zip"); InputStream in = zp.getInputStream (zp.getEntry ("Index.htm"));

Comment: I get this result: 
`      &nbsp;December 2011&nbsp;&nbsp;`

How can i omit &nbsp; in my string?